# Dictionary and Caching

Tags: c#, .net, caching, dictionary, hashcode

I've a class named Color which implements the following override:

```
public override Int32 GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        Int32 hash = 23;
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_Changes.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_Blue;
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_Green;
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_Random;
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_RandomBlue;
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_RandomGreen;
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_RandomRed;
        hash = (hash * 37) + m_Red;

        return hash;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to cache come results in order to reduce calculations:

```
public static Color Average(Color left, Color right, Double weight)
{
    Color value;
    Int32 key = left.GetHashCode() ^ right.GetHashCode() ^ weight.GetHashCode();

    if (!s_Averages.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        Double complement = 100.0 - weight;

        Int32 red = (Int32)(((left.Red * complement) + (right.Red * weight)) / 100.0);
        Int32 green = (Int32)(((left.Green * complement) + (right.Green * weight)) / 100.0);
        Int32 blue = (Int32)(((left.Blue * complement) + (right.Blue * weight)) / 100.0);
        Int32 random = (Int32)(((left.Random * complement) + (right.Random * weight)) / 100.0);
        Int32 randomRed = (Int32)(((left.RandomRed * complement) + (right.RandomRed * weight)) / 100.0);
        Int32 randomGreen = (Int32)(((left.RandomGreen * complement) + (right.RandomGreen * weight)) / 100.0);
        Int32 randomBlue = (Int32)(((left.RandomBlue * complement) + (right.RandomBlue * weight)) / 100.0);

        value = new Color(red, green, blue, randomRed, randomGreen, randomBlue, random, (left.Changes || right.Changes));
        s_Averages.Add(key, value);
    }

    return value;
}
```

The result is not good as I'm getting wrong pixels when I draw averaged colors on my screen. If I revert the method to the cacheless version everything works fine:

```
public static Color Average(Color left, Color right, Double weight)
{
    Double complement = 100.0 - weight;

    Int32 red = (Int32)(((left.Red * complement) + (right.Red * weight)) / 100.0);
    Int32 green = (Int32)(((left.Green * complement) + (right.Green * weight)) / 100.0);
    Int32 blue = (Int32)(((left.Blue * complement) + (right.Blue * weight)) / 100.0);
    Int32 random = (Int32)(((left.Random * complement) + (right.Random * weight)) / 100.0);
    Int32 randomRed = (Int32)(((left.RandomRed * complement) + (right.RandomRed * weight)) / 100.0);
    Int32 randomGreen = (Int32)(((left.RandomGreen * complement) + (right.RandomGreen * weight)) / 100.0);
    Int32 randomBlue = (Int32)(((left.RandomBlue * complement) + (right.RandomBlue * weight)) / 100.0);

    return (new Color(red, green, blue, randomRed, randomGreen, randomBlue, random, (left.Changes || right.Changes)));
}
```

This can only mean that they key I generate using GetHashCode is not unique. How can I manage this kind of cache getting a unique key for my color averages?

Comment: for instance: why do you think this is a suitable and unique key?: Int32 key = left.GetHashCode() ^ right.GetHashCode() ^ weight.GetHashCode();

Comment: Well, I don't think so from what this is producing... that's why I'm trying to find a good solution...

Comment: I _feel_ like even with the caching, the hashcode calculation and dictionary lookup might not make things _too_ much faster (unless you have _a lot_ of reused colours). Do you have a measurable bottleneck? Also, it's late so I might be wrong on this, but couldn't you pre-divide the `100.0` from `complement` and `weight` once rather than 6 times? (even so, that's a pretty minor optimization)

Comment: Problem is that I use hundreds of colors every 50 milliseconds. Rendering is working fine normally, but at the beginning and if by chance I have to calculate all of the colors I need to use for that frame everything slows down... that's why I was tryint to cache.
What do you mean with pre-dividing?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I don't think you are going to get a unique key
But you can do better
This suffers from if you switch left and right you get the same key.

```
Int32 key = left.GetHashCode() ^ right.GetHashCode() ^ weight.GetHashCode();
15 ^ 17 ^ 20 == 17 ^ 15 ^ 20
```

This will decrease key collisions

```
Int32 key = 17*left.GetHashCode() ^ 23*right.GetHashCode() ^ weight.GetHashCode();
```

Better yet can use an UInt64 key

```
UInt64 key = (((UInt64)left.GetHashCode() << 32) | (UInt64)right.GetHashCode()) ^ ((UInt64)weight.GetHashCode() << 30);
```

And look at how you average.
All of those colors are being cast to Double in the calculation and that has overhead.
How exact to that have to be?
If weight and complement were Int32 there would be some rounding error but it would be faster.

```
Int32 iweight = (Int32)(weight*100);   
Int32 icomplement = 10000 - weight;
Int32 red = ((left.Red * icomplement) + (right.Red * iweight)) / 10000;
```

Again this will have some rounding error but it will be faster.

And why are you using Int32?
Would UInt16 or Byte be sufficient?
Math is not faster but would reduce memory.

Comment: If you would answer the questions I asked then I could possibly improve the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution sensibly reduced my collisions but I'm still experiencing them. Do I have any kind of alternative different from using Dictionary<Tuple, Color> or calculating MD5/CRC32 for keys?

Comment: I repeat "If you would answer the questions I asked then I could possibly improve the answer".  I certainly did not recommend Tuple.  And no thanks for the the +1